# Using html5preloader to load and play audio files

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use html5loader js library to preload audio files.

My code looks like this:

```
var myLoader = html5Preloader();
myLoader.addFiles('mysound*:rattle1.ogg||rattle1.mp3'); 
myLoader.on('finish', function(){ alert('All assets loaded.'); });
myLoader.getFile('mysound').play();
```

I get an error:

TypeError: myLoader.getFile(...) is undefined (Firefox) and
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'play' of undefined  (Chrome)

What is wrong? The sound files are in the same folder as the .html file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but if I look at the code I would think the following is happening:

```
var myLoader = html5Preloader();

// Here the preloading of the soundfile starts
myLoader.addFiles('mysound*:rattle1.ogg||rattle1.mp3');

// While the soundfile is loading, you set the event
myLoader.on('finish', function(){ alert('All assets loaded.'); });

// The soundfile may not yet be ready loading and yet you are trying to play it!!
myLoader.getFile('mysound').play();
```

So I would think that the solution would be as follows (for example):

```
var myLoader = html5Preloader();
myLoader.on('finish', function(){ 
    // Start playing the sound once it's finished loading
    myLoader.getFile('mysound').play();
});
myLoader.addFiles('mysound*:rattle1.ogg||rattle1.mp3');
```